# How can I find a model from a value in a OneToMany relationship?

Tags: typescript, relationship, typeorm

I want to be able to find a user model based off a value inside of a OneToMany relationship.

Here is my function:

```
async getUserViaPlatform(provider: string, id: string) {
        return await this.webUserRepository.findOne({
            profiles: [{
                provider,
                platformID: id
            }]
        });
    }
```

The User model is:

```
@Entity()
export class WebUser {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number;

    @Column()
    name!: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    picture?: string;

    @OneToMany(type => WebProfile, webProfile => webProfile.user, { eager: true })
    profiles!: WebProfile[];

    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt!: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updatedAt!: Date;
}
```

And "WebProfile" is

```
@Entity()
export class WebProfile {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number;

    @Column()
    provider!: string;

    @Column()
    email!: string;

    @Column()
    platformID!: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => WebUser, user => user.profiles)
    user!: WebUser;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt!: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updatedAt!: Date;
}
```

I want a user to be found where they have a profile which matches the provider and id.
But all that seems to be happening right now is returning the first user no matter what i give to the function.

Comment: Please mention the type of database. Please post ur model so that other people can understand

Comment: Hey, I have edited my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `QueryBuilder` with a [join](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/joining-relations):

```ts
await this.webUserRepository.createQueryBuilder('webUser')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('webUser.profiles', 'profile')
    .where   ('profile.provider   = :provider', { provider: '...' })
    .andWhere('profile.platformID = :platformID', { platformID: '...' })
    .getOne();
```

Comment: Glad I could help you.